# How to obtain Calender ID through Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, javadoc

I have doubt regarding Google calendar API.I had created calendar using google calendar developer guide. I want to retrieve the calendar Id through program. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The final line in the [developer guide](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#CreatingCalendars) is:

```
CalendarEntry returnedCalendar = myService.insert(postUrl, calendar);
```

Look at the ID of `returnedCalendar`:

```
String id = returnedCalender.getId();
```

Comment: Thanks it work correctly it gave outputlike this

http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/calendars/montfortperungudi.edu.in_tkpd38ud4ovaksh2mt812kui10%40group.calendar.google.com
I want this only 
montfortperungudi.edu.in_tkpd38ud4ovaksh2mt812kui10@group.calendar.google.com
How to get like this

Comment: @megala: Find the index of the last slash, and take a substring from there?